# Way to pass value during Button on click to another component with async in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a difficulty in creating a dynamic application that will change the displayed values of a table when an api call is triggered.

The table contents will be refreshed when a button is pressed.

The button will determine the url link for the get api call

```
Component 1

<Button onClick={() => viewDetails()}>View Details</Button>

function viewDetails() {
const url= "url" +    detail +    "/details");
}
```

Then the url will send on another component, that will get the response

```
Component 2

const getServerData = async ({ filters, sortBy, pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

   const res = await axios.get(url)
}


export default function() {
const { rows, pageCount } = await getServerData({
      filters,
      sortBy,
      pageSize,
      pageIndex
    });

}
```

Is it possible to send the url to the other component?

If it is possible, how do I import/ export the const to retrieve in other component? And does it affect the performance of application if I will do it this way? Is there a better approach?

Comment: you can share the `state` using `Redux` or `MobX`. the other way, you can share the parent's `state`

Answer (score 1):

**ParentComponent.js**

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
  state = {
    url: '',
  }
  setURL = (url) => { this.setState({ url: url }) };

  render(){
    return (
      <>
        <Button onClick={this.setURL} />
        <Another url={this.state.url} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

**Button.js**

```
const Button = (props) => {
  return ( <button onClick={props.onClick}>button</button>);
}
```

**Another.js**

```
const Another = (props) => {

  console.log(props.url); // You can use updated URL
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you zynkn, is using hooks also possible in this solution?

Comment: @Dan You have to read article about 'useEffect' by Dan Abramov https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/